# How too create a bar chart in c++ without functions or arrays

Tags: c++, loops, bar-chart, sentinel

I've spent the past 5 hours trying too write this program, got halfway and realised I cant use arrays or functions, strings etc.

The problem is i need too create a program that reads integer values terminated by a sentinel value and displays a bar chart of single digit numbers(0-9). The chart shows the total number of occurrences for each number in the sequence.
Here is what i have so far

EDIT: THIS IS MY REVISED CODE

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   //initilise variables
    int num = 0, count0 = 0, count1 = 0,count2 = 0,count3 = 0,count4 = 0, 
count5 =0, count6 = 0,count7 = 0,count8 = 0,count9 = 0, value;
int SENTINEL = -1;

//get numbers till a -1 values has been entered
cout << "Please enter a number: ";
while(num != SENTINEL)
{
    cin >> num;

    //adds each occurrence of number entered
    switch(num)
{
    case 0:
        count0+= 1;
        break;
    case 1:
        count1+= 1;
        break;
    case 2: 
        count2+=1;
        break;
    case 3:
        count3+= 1;
        break;
    case 4:
        count4+= 1;
        break;
    case 5: 
        count5+= 1;
        break;
    case 6:
        count6+= 1;
        break;
    case 7:
        count7+= 1;
        break;
    case 8: 
        count8+= 1;
        break;
    case 9:
        count9+= 1;
        break;
    default:;
}
}

for(int rows = 0; rows < 10; rows++)
{
    cout << endl << rows << " | ";
    for(int c = 0; c < count0; c++)
    {
        {
            cout << "*" ;

        }
    }

}
```

EDIT:

Im having trouble with getting the for loop for my columns too output the * on just a single row. Any idea what i should change too allow that? So far, if i input 3 zero's(count0=3) it will display 3 "*", but on all 9 rows.

Comment: why shouldn't you use arrays or functions? If that's the case, you have a big problem there: `#include <iostream>` includes lots of functions, classes, tempaltes and other C++ stuff. Your question title reads liek "how do i make a table without saws, drills and wood planes?"

Comment: @ArneMertz yeah i know that, i think thats what makes this question hard. I asked my teacher, who said we can only use looping and conditionals, if arrays are used, he wont accept it :(.

Comment: Be careful, you use `num` before it it initialized in `while(num != SENTINEL)`. Its value is random if you don't init it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to count single digit numbers, then one way to go is to use 10 variables =)
int count0, count1... etc... then you have almost array so, you can count input and then output counted values..

Comment: this wouldnt work if the numbers were not in an ordered sequence i dont think?
say if the sequnce was 1 1 3 4 1 5 1 -1. would i test each varaible too see if it held a 1, then if it did say for each add them together too output 3 *?

Comment: why? you read a number from an input stream and then do something straight forward like `switch(value) { case 0: count0++; break case 1: count1++; break; etc... `. Looks ugly but if I understood task right will do the job.

Comment: so far i put the switch statement into the while loop, or should i place it outside?

Comment: you should put it in the loop

Answer (score 1):

What you *could* do:

1. Write the program with functions and arrays.
2. Erase the functions by putting their code wherever they are called, remember to set the arguments correctly.
3. Replace the arrays with N variables and their access with a huge switch/case:

   ```
    //arr[i] = 42;
    switch (i) {
    case 0: arr_0 = 42; break;
    case 1: arr_1 = 42; break;
    //...
    }
   ```

You could facilitate both by using macros, e.g. use Boost.Preprocessor to repeat the cases from 0 to N

What you *should* do: Say no. Tell your teacher that it's bullshit to not use the language's most basic features. But maybe wait with that until after he accepted your solution ;)

Comment: do you know how too stop values being input into the array with a sentinel value, such as -1?

Comment: you have that part right with your while loop. (but read the comments on the question - you have to initialize `num`)